# Techniques to distribute workload uniformly in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am writing to a DynamoDB table with 15k WCU and auto scaling enabled. However, I get upto 40k throttled write requests and my use capacity only reaches 5k WCU. The problem is that my data is heavily skewed and the partition key and the GSI on the table leads to hot keys. I can't change the design of the table since other applications depend on the table and it is already in production. Are there any ways that I can uniformly distribute the workload by maybe like this one https://datarus.wordpress.com/2015/05/04/fighting-the-skew-in-spark/ used in spark that I can use to distribute my workload more effectively?

Comment: Can you make any changes to the existing applications?

Comment: So we can't change the index or the partition key from one element to another. We need those to query the data for our business use cases at a fast enough rate. For eg. I can't change the secondary index from departmentId to some uniformly distributed key, since our applications want to query by departimentId. But we can make changes in the applications to add or remove a hash etc if doing that will make the dynamodb throughput higher.

Comment: AWS has some recommendations on how to use sharding to improve write throughput. Take a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html